# How can I parse JSON-like syntax that uses single quotes?

Tags: python, json

The JSON standard says strings must be delimited by double quotes, but people insist on passing around data in a format that's identical to JSON except for using single quotes to delimit strings.

What's the simplest way to safely decode strings like this

```
{'foo': null, 'bar': "Mac 'n Cheese"}
```

into a python structure like

```
{'foo': None, 'bar': "Mac 'n Cheese"}
```

Approaches that will **not** work are using `ast.literal_eval` (it doesn't understand null) or just using regexes to replace all single-quotes with double-quotes (strings won't be escaped properly).

Note: I'm well aware this is **not JSON** (as has been pointed out ad nauseam on several similar questions), but I need to be able to interact with sloppy APIs that produce data like this.

Comment: Some google searching turned up a [JSON parser](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) with a non-strict mode. That might do the job.

Comment: user2357112: Not bad. Could you post that as an answer and I'll upvote it?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turned up [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/), a JSON parser for Python with a non-strict mode capable of handling this format.